# How hard is to add video to my social media?

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-processing, social-networking

I am creating a social media app (MVP), and I can't afford the option to upload videos to it. It would be too expensive.

One of my friends gave an option to just use a link from a video website. For example, as a user informs a link from a Youtube video which is already up and running on Youtube, we can show that video on our platform. Apparently, the user who see the post won't be able to tell if that video was updated to our plataform or is running from Youtube.

Is that really possible? If so, do you think it's ok to implement that in the MVP? Also, as the video and image are together in a post, that video from Youtube may need to cropped to a different aspect ratio to be the same as the pictures in that post.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. It's very hard to understand your problem here. Yes you could just upload the videos to Youtube via their API (which is free I believe) but it's probably not the best solution, but it's duable and not that complex.

Comment: Thanks @Trisma. Yeah, I know it's hard to understand, as it's quite complex problem at least for me hahaha. I may be wrong, but I don't think I am legally allowed to upload videos to Youtube as a social media. My solution is to give the user the opportunity to inform a Youtube link, so I can reproduce the video from that link on the platform. So, I won't upload the video, but I will reproduce a video which is already up and running on Youtube. Does it make more sense?

My question is, would that be hard to implement?